# Django serialize custom user model

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I have  CustomUser model which inherits from AbstractUser clas. I have a serializer which throw me following errors:

- When I use from django.contrib.auth.models import User, the error is "AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute '_meta'".
- When I use from users.models import User, the error is "'QuerySet' object has no attribute 'email'", but the email field exists within the model.

Here is what my serializer looks like:

```
from rest_framework import serializers
from users.models import User
# from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class DepartmentSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Department
        fields = ['id', 'title', 'is_active']

class CustomUserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    department = DepartmentSerializer()

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ['id', 'email', 'ad_login', 'sap', 'user_type', 'language', 'first_name', 'last_name', 'department']
```

In my settings I have also defined "AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'users.User'".
Hoping this is enough information, what may be the cause of these errors?

Comment: Have you run `makemigrations` and `migrate`? Are you sure the email field is in your DB table ?

Comment: Yes all migrations are done

Answer (score 0):

I found the issue: In my ViewSet I have to add the many=True option like :

```
serializer = self.get_serializer(customusers, many=True)
```